# Как поменять цвет фона и шрифта компонента webBrowser?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Компонент webBrowser отображает файлы и папки при помощи данного кода. Фон всегда белый, мне это совсем не нравится. Можно ли изменить цвет фона и шрифта на другой?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\");
    }
```

Comment: Отображать список файловой системы через `WebBrowser` - это "костыль", и от него лучше отказаться совсем.

Comment: Через какие компоненты отображать список файловой системы будет лучше?

Comment: OpenFileDialog, SaveFileDialog, свой компонент на основе ListView.

Comment: И все же можно изменить цвет фона и шрифта?

Comment: В своем компоненте - можно, особенно если это ListView из WPF, в стандартных диалогах тоже возможно, хотя придется иметь дело с WinAPI и будет тяжело.

Comment: А есть конкретный пример как поменять все это в webBrowser? Я даже не представляю как это сделать.

Comment: В данном случае компонент `WebBrowser` работает как Проводник Windows и использует текущие настройки пользователя ОС. Попробуйте изменять свойства папок и убедитесь в этом сами. Так что, полагаю, прямого способа изменить фон и шрифт нет.